Passing dynamic date range from Crystal to stored procedure
I have to create a table of a facility daily population based on multiple demographics (total daily average, male daily average, etc) then calculated into a daily average per each. I can run this straight via crystal obviously but it is a massive amount of data and takes forever to run. I created a stored procedure which pulls the total count for each demographic per day. This has one parameter called reportdate. Works great if I pull it into Crystal on a single day or via SQL per single day.
My crystal report runs in such a way the user selects which Quarter they want (q1, q2 etc) and the date range is automatically calculated based on that input. The date fields in the correct range populate via a calendar table.
What I want is for each day of this range to be passed through the ReportDate parameter of the stored procedure and return the results.
In my Crystal report when it prompts for the ReportDate via the stored procedure, I can not figure out how to get it to link to my CalendarDate and loop through. Ultimately I will need to be able to add up each one and divide by the number of days in the range for the overall daily average.
Is this possible? I would really like to be able to run this with my user just selecting the quarter they want and everything else automatically calculating.
I have tried linking the parameter via database expert, via record selection, reformatting the date parameters to verify they matched. I have also tried putting a startdate and enddate parameter into my stored procedure but still run into the same issue of passing the auto-calculated Crystal parameter into the stored procedure and calculating for each date.

One solution would be to use a subreport:

Have your calendar based dataset in the main report solely.
Then insert a sub report which calls your stored proc, parameterized with a single date,
place this subreport in the details section of the main report,
and link main report's date data field to sub report's date parameter.


Unfortunately I need to be able to do math on each of these and having the data in a subreport doesn't allow me to do that. Unless I try to make it into a shared variable that can kick back the data into the main report but it is getting awful messy at that point. Hoping for a cleaner solution via a SP.

@kayross27 AFAIK, there is no way for CR to communicate data back to anything.  It may be possible to create a .NET app that may be able to accomplish what you need, but it would need to query the database and pivot the data in a way that creates a single datasource that can be bound to the Crystal Report.  This could get very complex very quickly though.
